# Maintain Useful commented codes in separate class in C#

Tags: c#, refactoring, comments, simplify

I have a useful commented codes in every classes as below which are used for future references .Is there is any alternative way to effectively maintain commented codes in difference class and can be used only for reference purpose .

```
//3986 TEST 1199 PROD
//3986 TEST 1199 PROD
//2179 TEST 118 PROD
//3986 TEST 1199 PROD
//3986 TEST 11199 PROD
```

[image: Click here for code]

Comment: Are there alternatives? Sure, separate files, in a database, source control, attributes, etc. But it is really difficult to tell if any alternative is *good* without understanding why the comments exist and what they are for. The general recommendation is to use comments to explain what the code is for, but your usage seem to be for something else.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want here, but (in visual studio at least, I don't know if this is a standard for the whole lang or just that ide), you can put 
///<summary>
/// Desc Here
/// </summary>
to write a description for a class or function that will show up when you hover over it